# Cannot find name 'require'. (React + Typescript)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting this error: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.

The problem is on server.ts, this is the very first time I'm creating a server file with Typescript so I don't have much knowledge

But Types/node is already in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@carbon/icons-react": "^10.10.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "carbon-components": "^10.11.2",
    "carbon-components-react": "^7.11.3",
    "carbon-icons": "^7.0.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-history-api-fallback": "^2.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.13.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34"
  }
}
```

server.ts:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fallback = require('express-history-api-fallback');

const app = express();
```

Comment: How do you run the server? What's your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Answer (score 0):

In typescript you should use `import` syntax instead of `require` for including modules. For example:

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
```